# Change id column name in cakephp(in the Db the id column has different name)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

I know i have to declare the unique column(PK) with ID.But the database is already exist,
and was created with a different name(Reg_name) than ID.How can i set in cakephp to use Reg_name insted of id?

Comment: It's really not that hard to find **https://google.com/search?q=cakephp+custom+primary+key+name**

Answer (score 0):

```
var $primaryKey = 'example_id';
```